# Response error in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> Here What I have got as a response

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

> This is the Postman response

```
[
    [
        {
            "@id": 1,
            "name": "approval",
            "figure": "15",
            "type": "tile",
            "function": "auxxa.Approval",
            "url": "https://api.auxxa.com/BIMobile/GetApprovals"
        },
        {
            "@id": 1,
            "name": "returnCheque",
            "figure": "158,000.00",
            "type": "tile",
            "function": "auxxa.ReturnCheque",
            "url": "https://api.auxxa.com/BIMobile/GetApprovals"
        },
        {
            "@id": 1,
            "name": "notification",
            "figure": "12",
            "type": "tile",
            "function": "auxxa.Notification",
            "url": "https://api.auxxa.com/BIMobile/GetApprovals"
        }
    ]
]
```

> Here I post my fetch method

```
fetch(url, {
  method: "GET"
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseData => {
    //set your data here
    console.log("Landing Data " + responseData[0]);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

> Could not find the actual issue.Please help me to sort out this issue.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: make it `,` instead of `+`. `console.log("Landing Data " , responseData[0]);` . It will just print the data, but you will get whole idea of your responce

Comment: @RaviRupareliya post this as an answer…

Comment: @feeela Do you believe this should be an answer? I mean its just one character change :)

Comment: Thanks that is the answer (Y)

Comment: @HRCJ Ok thn, let me post as answer if it realy helped. feeela thanks to you also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it `,` instead of `+`.

```
console.log("Landing Data " , responseData[0]);
```

It will just print the data, but you will get whole idea of your responce

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an array inside an array as response. Try accessing the first entry in each array and it should work.

You should also not use `+` with a string and an array. Log them separately instead with `,`:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseData => {
    console.log("Landing Data", responseData[0][0]);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> console.log("Landing Data", responseData[0][0]);